# How to control user role selection in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, security, role

I am working on asp.net for my website. Actually my site have two types of roles admin and user. I saw in asp.net development site at create new wizard user have a selection for roles like admin and user but if a crazy user may select admin role though he is a normal user so how could i control the user role selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my optionion you should not rely on the wizard which ships with asp.net.
You should have your own control over creating users.

I would start to look at the Membership api to see how to access it from source code, how to add roles and how to authenticate... this is basically how the wizard magic works...

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/authentication
http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx

HTH